# How to Setup tomcat, so you can access it from the VPN Server you are connected to?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I try my best to describe this oddly specific problem:

I need to do some testing on a programm that runs on a **tomcat server**. 
An external Software should send requests to our server and we should send a response. The Problem is we are not allowed to recieve anything from outside of our Network and **can't open a VPN** because of security restrictions.

We can send to the outside and recieve responses.

It is possible to connect to a VPN and send to the VPN Network, but i can't recieve any requests from outside. I am allowed send to the VPN Addres an recieve responses.
But i need to recieve a request, without opening our Network.

Is there any way, that I can configure the address of my Tomcat connector, to the VPN Address, so that I can recieve requests that are sent in the VPN network ?

Comment: We typically use https://ngrok.com to create tunnels for testing inside the network.

Comment: If it is your company policy to not allow outside access to your machines, don't attempt to violate it, assuming you want to keep your job. Why would you need *external* software to do the testing, anyway? But, if you really do need that, then you should *ask for an exception*, and they can open access through the firewall. Most likely, you'd have to move the server into the DMZ. Talk to the network admin and/or your manager.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to set-up a DEV environment to simulate the context you are describing .

Inside the VPN set up SOAP UI to simulate external requests going to your Tomcat based solution .

Then , when your testing is complete , promote to PROD to face the real world . If your SOAP UI simulation is accurate you are golden .